# How store value in variable in for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using for loop in javascript and store value in multiple variables.

```
 var    friend_id1 = '';
 var    friend_id2 = '';
 var    friend_id3 = '';

 FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    if(response.data) {
        obj = response.data
        obj = shuffle(obj);
        a = 3;
        for(x = 1; x <= obj.length; x++){
            friend_id[x] = obj[x].id;
        if(x >= a) break;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

if i replace friend_id[x] to friend_id1 i will get user id. But i want store values in multiple variables.

Comment: why dont you use an array/object for  friend_id1,  friend_id2,  friend_id3 in the first place ??

Comment: I was about to say that =)

Comment: something like `var friends = {};` and in your loop just use `friends['friend_id_' + x] = obj`

Comment: I am submit these variables into ajax form

Comment: As @HassanNisarKhan said, instead of having friend_id1... friend_idn try creating an array say `var friends = []` and then you can insert the values like so `friends.push(obj[i])`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save the values to an array:

```
friend_id[x] = obj[x].id;
```

But you didn't declare an array, you have no array variable called `friend_id`.  Instead, you have multiple variables with numbered names.

Just declare the array as you want to use it:

```
var friend_id = [];
```

Or, more aptly named:

```
var friend_ids = [];
```

And more properly used:

```
friend_ids.push(obj[x].id);
```